# Caching specific Javascript and CSS files

Tags: asp.net, iis, browser-cache

How can I cache a few specific JavaScript & CSS files. I found advice from this site to put this in my `.htaccess` file

```
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE css js
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
```

But it is incomplete. What is `.htaccess` and how do I create it, where to store it, in my web root folder?

What is the meaning of the following statements:

```
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE css js
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
```

I dont want to cache all my Javascript & CSS files rather just a few specific files which will never change.

How can I do this?

Comment: What web server are you using? `.htaccess` is a control file for the Apache web server. If you are using IIS it has no meaning.

Comment: i will use IIS...so please advise me what should i do. what i need to write in my asp.net file to cache few specific js & css file. plzz discuss in detail. thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can configure IIS to cache specific files by extension. For example:

Select the folder where your css/js files reside and then click on Output Caching.
[image]

Then add the file extensions that you want to cache:

[image]

I don't think you can specify which ones to cache on a per file basis unless you write an http <s>handler</s> module to add the appropriate headers for each file independently, but from IIS this is how is done.

Then you can verify that you are getting 304 responses using firebug / fiddler or your tool of choice.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: can i cache js & css file by http handler....if so can point me any good article for this.

Comment: @user750398 look at this article: http://blog.sb2.fr/post/2008/11/21/EN-Css-Caching-and-Compression-with-HttpModule-for-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: `Output Caching` is not the same as controlling browser cache. They are quite different. `Output Caching` allows IIS to internally cache dynamic page content so that it can serve it to the client faster. It has no effect on the client's browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

That's cool i would anyways add a file revisions and make IIS cache css + js files.
As Icarus specified.

Then if you update the files on the server just add a new revision number this could also be a timestamp.

- http://particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/
- http://davidwalsh.name/prevent-cache (just the opposite)
- http://betterexplained.com/articles/speed-up-your-javascript-load-time/
- http://www.die.net/musings/page_load_time/
- http://ajaxpatterns.org/Patterns#Performance_Optimisation

Answer (score 0):

1. AddOutputFilter DEFLATE: output is compressed(usually gzip) before
   sent to server in this case `css & js` your css and js.
2. ExpiresActive On: Sets `Expires` and cache control headers to On
3. ExpiresByType: Set the expire rule for the content type in this case `application/x-javascript` to a month `A2592000 => 24 * 3600 * 30` its in `ms`.

I would recommend to instead of handling specific js via .htaccess you should add a revisions number to your js files, ala:

`<script src="link/to/file.js?rev=xxx"></script>`

Then when you update your files just update the rev number.
And your clients will automatically be served the new files.

Resources:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html
- http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/htaccess/