# Replace keywords in Visual Studio on publish?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble with caching on my website. I have static files that should usually be cached for weeks or months, but need to be updated right away for users if I make changes to the files. To get around this, I thought of having something like:

```
<script src="js/masterPage.js?v=$$Number$$" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, I need a script to change `$$Number$$` into a number. It doesn't really matter what the number is, so long as it is different every time.

I could write a script to go through my do this kind of processing, but if there is some way to do this automatically when I hit "Publish" in visual studio it would be really handy. What possibilities are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that. You can let IIS handle it for you by sending 304 HTTP responses until your files are modified. I answered a similar question like this here. [Take a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541032/caching-specific-javascript-and-css-files/7542816#7542816)