# IIS/ASP Caching

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, caching, iis-6

We are running Windows 2003, IIS 6 and ASP 2.0.50727.  I am not very familiar with IIS/ASP caching.  We have an application that makes the same requests over and over. (static content as well as dynamic asp requests)  From what I have seen the only way to use caching with ASP is to do it at the code level.  Is this true?  I am not a developer but work on the systems side.

Do you recommend setting Expire HTTP Headers at the IIS level?  If I set it to 1 day will this only cache static content for 1 day or also dynamic asp data?  I know this caches it at the clients browser.  Is there a way to cache these images on the IIS server side?  It stores the files in memory?

Thanks

Comment: Expires controls caching on the users end, not the server side. Rick has a good start for controlling it.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, this is, IMO, the best way to do caching on IIS, specially for images, js files, css files, etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541032/caching-specific-javascript-and-css-files/7542816#7542816

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately I am running IIS 6 so I don't have the "Output Caching" option in IIS.  I have read about Kernal caching with IIS 6 but not sure if its the same or not.

Comment: Icarus, this setting is in IIS correct?  When I right click on my Images folder I don't see Output caching as an option anywhere.  Its not under properties and it doesn't have the new panel with all the options that include Output caching.  Can you give me more details on where exactly I would see this option in IIS 6?  Based on a few links I found this feature was started with IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

You can control overall caching in the web.config:

[Cache Configuration in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178606%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link Rick.  Quick question, I don't see anything like: <outputCacheSettings>
  <outputCacheProfiles>
    <add name="CacheProfile1" duration="60" />
  </outputCacheProfiles>
</outputCacheSettings>

section in my web.config or machine.config.  Do you have to add this?  I only see: <httpModules> <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule"/>.  And is this essentially setting a 60 second server-side cache for all static file requests?  How about dynamic asp requests?

Comment: We essentially have an ASP application that serves up lots of static pages (images,css,js,etc) and then also makes an asp request to a web service and waits for the response.  Each asp request will be dynamic as its a different user in which data will be provided for.

Comment: you have to add it. webconfigs start at the most basic and the rest is assumed to be default. As you change things in IIS you will notice it adds/changes things in the webconfig. You can add things to the webconfig to specify alternate settings.