# Set cache expiration date in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching, optimization

I am currently working to make my page optimized.I came across the cache expiry.I studied about it and how it works.I got the following code to be added in web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="14.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

But when i test my web page with yslow ,it still says set expiry header for css,js,image files.Infact addding this code brings no change in the yslow grade.I tried other example as well such as

```
`<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="browser"  %>`
```

And it does affect the rating,rating increase by one.But still the css,image,js files are not getting the expiry date.

Do i need to change anything else then the webconfig file to add expiry header to css,js files.?

DO i need to make change in iis?

I am testing my offline localhost site by the way?

**Please help!**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541032/caching-specific-javascript-and-css-files

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that happens is, ASP.Net does not serve the CSS, JS, images, etc files. Those are static files and ASP.Net processing pipeline just ignores them leaving those for the IIS server to serve. If you want to achieve caching on those files, you should set Caching properties in your Web server. That would be in addition to the settings you have already done in the web.config.

Depending upon which version of IIS Server you are using, the Caching headers can be set differently.