# How to fix 'Add Expires headers' in IIS?

Tags: iis, optimization

I test my website in GTmetrix and this website get this suggestion that

> Add Expires headers

I search on the internet and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541032/caching-specific-javascript-and-css-files) but this solution does not work for me.When I  try to fix such as up link get error that this output cache exist.
[image]

[Test My website in GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.travelenter.com/IhQTdHfp)

I set http Response Header such as blow image but does not solve.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Output cache is server side caching. The "Add Expires headers" you are receiving is about browser caching. [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661(v=ws.10).aspx) article describes how to set this so browsers will cache the resources.

Comment: I checked https://www.travelenter.com/Content/Travelo/images/logo.png and it sets Cache-Control:"no-cache,max-age=86400" in the response header. The max-age is set correctly but i think you need to get rid off the no-cache piece.